# bash: utime: command not found

Tags: bash, debian, command

I have been working on some tasks and I used `utime` to limit execution time of some procedures. It was working well at first, but after few calls it stopped. I checked `history` so I could see what could cause it, but have not found anything suspicious:

```
 1952  time find /usr > users
 1953  less users 
 1954  ulimit -a
 1955  ulimit -t 1
 1956  time find /usr > users_limited
 1957  time find /etc > etc_limited
 1958  sudo time find /etc > etc_limited
 1959  time find /Desktop > cos
 1960  time find /home/two/Desktop/ > desktop
 1961  ulimit -t 1; time find /home/two/pycharm-community-2020.2.2/ > pycharm
 1962  ls
 1963  less pycharm 
 1964  rm pycharm etc_limited users_limited desktop cos
 1965  ls
 1966  ulimit -t 1
 1967  time find /usr > users_new
 1968  utime -t 1; time ../../pycharm-2020.2.2/bin/pycharm.sh > pycharm
 1969  utime -t 5; time ../../pycharm-2020.2.2/bin/pycharm.sh > pycharm
 1970  utime -t 5
 1971  utime
```

It stopped working exactly in execution of 1969th instruction, then I started receiving `bash: utime: command not found` in following calls. I use Debian 10.

I already tried:

1. checking whether my `$PATH` was changed anyhow, but it was not;
2. calling `type time` and `type utime`, first one returns `time is a shell keyword` and the latter `bash: type: utime: not found`.

Comment: Unix caches files accessed from the filesystem, which is probably why subsequent calls are not reaching limits. You seem to swap from using `ulimit` to `utime` - there is no such command as `utime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your history, you've used `ulimit` (not `utime`). Typo perhaps?

Comment: Oh god, that is it. I was literally looking for the mistake since over 1 hour. Thank you!